# What is effective price of suger

Tags: proof-verification

The price of sugar was  Rs$25.00$ on January. It got increased in February by 40%. In March the price was reduced by 40%. The new price will be:

My solution:

$25[1+0.4][1-0.4]=21$ Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The original price = Rs $25$

Got increased to $40\%$ in Feb $= 25\Big(1+\frac{40}{100}\Big) = 25\times 1.4 $. This is the new price

Got decreased to $40\%$ in Mar $= 25\times 1.4\times\Big(1-\frac{40}{100}\Big) = 21$.

You did it correctly.